# Apple Wallet - Pass added successfully but not getting updated

Tags: ios, swift, apple-wallet

I am able to add pass received from server to Apple wallet but not getting why pass not getting updated. Apple documentation confused me more thus, my queries are:

1. Who will create pass if it needs to be updated from backend automatically without my iOS app interaction
2. What is the role of my iOS app in handling pass(adding updating data in Apple Wallet)
3. Who will register for push notifications after pass added to wallet and who will get push token
4. At whose end backend or app end this api will be called

   [https://yourpasshost.example.com/v1/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}](https://yourpasshost.example.com/v1/devices/%7BdeviceLibraryIdentifier%7D/registrations/%7BpassTypeIdentifier%7D/%7BserialNumber%7D)

Below is my code for adding pass to wallet:

```
 let passURL = URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iospasswallet.appspot.com/o/pass1.pkpass?alt=media&token=397cb8-d939-4241-b8f8-a1f7e4f8d937")!

    // Use URLSession to download pass data asynchronously
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: passURL) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error downloading pass data: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let passData = data else {
            print("Failed to get pass data")
            return
        }

        do {
            let pass = try PKPass(data: passData)
            let passLibrary = PKPassLibrary()
            passLibrary.addPasses([pass]) { (status) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if status.rawValue == 0 {
                        print("Pass added successfully")
                    } else if status.rawValue == 1 {
                        print("Pass review successfully")
                    } else {
                        print("Cancelled Status: \(status.rawValue)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error creating pass: \(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Thanks in advance.